# How to setup Django default function?

Tags: django, django-settings

I'm not sure that my question is correct.
I develop a web site on local machine and I can not understand how to setup a view which will be executed when I open a start page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

I've tried to write a url - url(r'^/', 'pages.views.home', name='home'), but when I go to browser it doesn't work.

Maybe I need to change settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following URL regex:

```
url(r'^$', 'pages.views.home', name='home')
```

The first `/` is not part of the regex because its automatically removed before comparison against the URLs. The above expression will match the first `/` and nothing more - `^` means 'beginning of the line' and `$` means the end.

Comment: @NodariLipartiya no problem - accept the answer if it worked :) Jay - only if you need them. I find function-based views easier to work with for the majority of my projects.